# SQL Azure import slow, hangs, but local import takes 3 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have a not-that-large database that I'm trying to migrate to SQL Azure, about 1.6 gigs. I have the BACPAC file in blob storage, start the import, and then... nothing. It gets to 5% as far as the status goes, but otherwise goes nowhere fast. After 10 hours, the database size appears to be 380 MB, and the monitoring shows on average around 53 successful connections per hour, with no failures. It appears to still be going.

I took the same BACPAC to my local machine at home, and I can import the same database in just under three minutes, so I'm making the assumption that the integrity of the file is all good.

What could possibly be the issue here? I can't just keep the app I'm migrating offline for days while this goes on. There must be something fundamentally different that it's choking on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ugh, I hate answering my own question, but I figured out what the issue is. It appears to have to do with their new basic-standard-premium tiers (announced April 2014). The database imports to the old web-business levels no problem. Because the new tiers are built around throttling for "predictable performance," they make the high volume transactions of importing crazy slow.

Comment: This is undoable. Does anyone have tips for a workaround?

Comment: The workaround is to scale up your database. Now that they bill it hourly instead of by day, it's a reasonable expense.

Answer (score 3):

I've yet to try this myself (spent 5 hours so far today waiting for a ~11GB Test database to import to an S3 sized Azure SQL database)...

But MS themselves mention that is due to them not assigning enough hamsters to run the wheel, and suggest using SQLPackage.exe direct from the command line as a workaround for slow imports. (see here: [Azure SQL Database and Managed Instance Import/Export service takes a long time to import or export a database](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/2965554/azure-sql-database-import-export-service-takes-a-long-time-to-import-o))

Interested to see what will happen, I can't wait this long to migrate the Prod DB in a few days' time so will give this tool a try!

UPDATE:

After waiting 4+ hours for my BACPAC file to import, it crashed.

Interestingly, the database from the crashed import was present in the Azure Portal, and I could see the DTU usage (S3 database) had been railed at 100% for almost the whole 4 hours...

So I wondered what happens if I set the DB performance ALL THE WAY UP in the import process, so I deleted the DB from crashed import and started it again, this time with the performance set to P15 (4000DTUs vs. 40 from an S2).

Guess what...

The import took just a little over **3 MINUTES**

Turned the DB back down to S3 (what the client has spec'ed and is happy to pay for).

That's 4 hours of my life I'll never get back...

Comment: Don't post two answers for same question, edit the previous one and update your answer.

Comment: @ArunJ Sorry I was unaware or the rules and etiquette on this site at the time I posted the second answer. Second answer has been deleted and first one updated with my findings.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar situation.  I periodically delete then re-create an Azure SQL Server database during scheduled maintenance events.  This time while importing a 2.5 GB bacpac file into an Azure SQL Server the import process was stuck at 1% after 4 hours.  It has historically required between 15 and 30 minutes, with time increasing as the file size increases.

I changed the pricing tier to S12 Standard 3000 DTUs 250 GB from S2 Standard 50 DTUs 250 GB to see if this would either crash the import or speed it up.  Fast forward 30 minutes and it was still stuck at 1%.

I realized that I still had MSSMS running on my computer which has a persistent connection to the Azure SQL Server DB that was being replaced (Server Objects > Linked Servers > AZUREDB > Catalogs > MyDatabaseName).

Within seconds of exiting out of MSSMS, the import process completed.  Exiting MSSMS was one of the procedural steps before initiating bacpac import, but at 4:30AM I inadvertently skipped it.